# Why can't there be 4 Activity Lifecycles in Android?

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I'm not understanding why there are multiple lifecycles for each particular phase? Do I need code for all 11 lifecycles? Can I just have code in onCreate, onPause, onResume, and onStop? **It seems like there is a redundancy** (and looking at other SO posts on this question others have thought the same, but after reading the replies I can't CONFIDENTLY say I still understand why)

Phase 1:

```
onCreate()
onStart()
onResume()
```

Phase 2:

```
onPause()
onStop()
```

Phase 3:

```
onRestart()
onStart()
onResume()
```

Phase 4:

```
onPause()
onStop()
onDestroy()
```

Comment: This is how Android works, Every method in activity lifecycle have it's own importance.

Comment: There is no obligation to implement all lifecycle methods. If there is nothing to do for a certain event just don't implement the respective method.

Answer (score 0):

As a user navigates through, out of, and back to your app, the `Activity` instances in your app transition through different states in their lifecycle.The Activity class provides a number of callbacks that allow the activity to know that a state has changed: that the system is creating, stopping, or resuming an activity, or destroying the process in which the activity resides.

**onCreate**    called when activity is first created.

**onStart** called when activity is becoming visible to the user.

**onResume**    called when activity will start interacting with the user.

**onPause** called when activity is not visible to the user.

**onStop**  called when activity is no longer visible to the user.

**onRestart**   called after your activity is stopped, prior to start.

**onDestroy**   called before the activity is destroyed.

> You can get more details about an Activity Lifecycle here :
>   https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

> why there are multiple lifecycles for each particular phase?

Well there are N number of applications and N number of usecases that are implemented on Android. The features provided by app are user centric and all the care and phases ensure smooth and better user-experience. As a user navigates through, out of, and back to your app, the Activity instances in your app transition through different states in their lifecycle. You need these to handle the behavior correctly

> Can I just have code in onCreate, onPause, onResume, and onStop?

It all depends on your usecase, the android component you are using and how gracefully you want to handle the life-cycle changes.

All the 7 callback methods (`onCreate()`, `onStart()`, `onResume()`, `onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onRestart()`, `onDestroy()`) in the Activity life-cycle serve different purposes.

> **Good implementation of the lifecycle callbacks can help ensure that
>   your app avoids:**
>
> - Crashing if the user receives a phone call or switches to another app while using your app.
> - Consuming valuable system resources when the user is not actively using it. Losing the user's progress if they leave your app and return
>     to it at a later time.
> - Crashing or losing the user's progress when the screen rotates between landscape and portrait orientation.

You can follow the comprehensive [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#lc) which describes in detail the scenario in which you need to implement different callback.